# How to check if a route path exists in phoenix router

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix generates automatically the helpers to generate the urls associated to the routes of the router.

**Example:**

```rb
scope "/", Zombie.App, as: :app do
  pipe_through :browser

  get "/", PageController, :home # app_page_path()
  get "/about", ZombieController, :about # app_zombie_path()
end
```

How is it possible to know if a specific path helper exists in my application ?

Answer (score 1):

I would use `Kernel.function_exported?`.

```
iex(3)> if function_exported?(NewAdmin.Router.Helpers, :group_path, 2), do: "yes", else: "no"
"yes"
iex(4)>
```

Comment: Sounds another great solution, but looks like you need to specify the arity.

Answer (score 0):

It's straightforward, let's say you want to know if the path helper **app_zombie_path()** exists, you could do:

```rb
path = :app_zombie_path
router_paths = Zombie.Router.Helpers.__info__(:functions)

if Keyword.has_key?(router_paths, path) do
  # The path exists
end
```